# Estimating the size of a sub-sample of a known population distribution given only the max and min values of the sub-sample

Tags: probability

Suppose you have $n$ objects labeled $1, 2, ..., n$ and $m$ of these objects are chosen with equal probability without replacement. The labels for each of the samples are denoted by $X_1, ..., X_m$. What are some effective ways to estimate $m$ if all you observe are $\min X_i$ and $\max X_i$?

Comment: Might this be related to the [German Tank Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem)?

Comment: @Max, thanks for the reference but I think that problem (using the way I've framed my question) is concerned with the case where $n$ is unknown and needs to be estimated. I'm interested in the case where $n$ is known but the size of the sample, $m$, is not.

Comment: My apologies. I was confused. Out of curiosity, what's motivating this question? Also, have you considered doing some maximum likelihood estimation based on order statistics or simulation?

Comment: @Max, actually this is a simplified version of something that came up while playing in a poker tournament online. The site I was playing on doesn't tell you exactly how many people are left. But, it does list the tables, sorted by table number. It is hard to count the number of tables since there may be hundreds of tables and it refreshes itself as you scroll through. It is easy to see the max and min number, though. I'm making the simplifying assumption that there are the same number of people at each table (this is usually true) and the table number is independent of the play at the table.

Comment: @Max, so my goal is a quick way to figure out how many people are left without counting them manually. I'm just looking for a good estimator that is only a function of the max and min. Maximum likelihood estimation is a possibility but I'm having a bit of trouble deriving the joint likelihood of the max and the min, as a function of $m$. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused about the question. Initially this tournament has $n$ tables numbered $1$ through $n$. Tables are removed from the tournament at various times. My question is this: As tables are removed from the tournament, are the remaining labels adjusted to account for the total number of tables remaining? For example, let's say the tournament begins with $10$ tables and the first table to be removed from the tournament is table $7$. Are tables $8$, $9$, and $10$ relabeled as $7$, $8$, and $9$, respectively?

Comment: @Max, No, the tables are not relabeled. They retain their original tables throughout the tournament. Also, the program seems to automatically re-balance tables so that all tables have about the same (maximal) number of people, and this process is how certain tables get removed. For example, if there were 3 tables of size 4,5,9 then the first two would be combined into one table, randomly selecting which one of the two remains. If tables got relabeled throughout the tournament, I can see that one would simply need to look at the max number.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any effective way to do this without knowing something about the distribution of the X$_i$.  But if for example the you know that the X$_i$ have an absolutely continuous distribution then you know max X$_i$ increases to b and the min X$_i$ decrease to a.

But it takes more to estimate m.  Let's assume X$_i$ has a uniform dsitribution.  Then E[Max X$_i$]-E[Min X$_i$]  is a function of the sample size and b-a.  So m can be estimated by comparing Max X$_i$-Min X$_i$ to b-a.

Now that I see that the distribution is uniform on the integers from 1 to n something can be said.  You can calculate E[max X$_i$] and E[min X$_i$] as a function of m and n and use the value of Max Xi and Min X$_j$ to estimate m.  However it is possible that Max X$_i$ =n and Min X$_j$=1 in which case you have nothing to help you estimate m.

Comment: I think the distribution of the $X_i$ has been given - it is the $i$'th selection from a sequence of equal probability samples without replacement from the list of numbers $1,2,...,n$. My question is, if all I know are the max and the min number drawn, can I estimate the number of samples that were drawn?

Comment: Sorry for not reading carefully.  In this case you have a discrete uniform on the integers from 1 to n.  It is possible that the max = n and the min = 1 and if that happens you have no information to help you determine m.

Comment: are you sure there would be no information? It seems that if max = n and min = 1, this makes it more likely that $m$ is a larger number, i.e. closer to n. Similarly, if max=min, then you know $m=1$, or max=min+1, then you know $m=2$, etc. If $n$ were much larger than $m$, these kind of obvious cases aren't likely to arise but in general I'm thinking some kind of reasonable estimator is possible.

Comment: @Wiener.Snausage I guess it would be more appropriate to say that there is very little information in that case.  It is possible for Max=n and Min=1 for any n>=k>=2.